# Using.tolower function with vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm struggling on some coding and was hoping someone could help me out please, what I'm trying to do is read a text file and convert column2 in to lowercase and save it again.

But I get Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo'.  after .ToLower?

```
  Dim Convertcolumn = From line In System.IO.File.ReadLines("Path")
              Select line.Split(" "c)(1) & line.ToLower(1)
    Dim writer As IO.StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter("Path2")

    For Each line In Convertcolumn
        writer.Write((line) & Environment.NewLine)
    Next
```

Updated coding:

```
Dim Convertcolumn = From line In System.IO.File.ReadLines("C:\Test1.txt")
                    Select line.Split(" "c)(1) & line.Split(" "c)(1).ToLower()

Dim writer As IO.StreamWriter = New IO.StreamWriter("C:\Test2.txt")

For Each line In Convertcolumn
    writer.Write((line) & Environment.NewLine)
Next
```

Sorry when i added the comments its not showing as columns the data looks like this

```
D00001 BLACK user
D00002 BLACK user
```

and i want to change it to

```
D00001 black user
D00002 black user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code can't work when the file contains columns.  You'll need:

```
    Using parser = New FileIO.TextFieldParser("Path")
        parser.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        parser.Delimiters = New String() {" "}
        Using writer = New IO.StreamWriter("Path2")
            While True
                Dim words = parser.ReadFields()
                If words Is Nothing Then Exit While
                If words.Length > 1 Then words(1) = words(1).ToUpper
                writer.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", words))
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

`line.ToLower(1)`  is not valid.

`ToLower` takes no paramters.

I assume you mean to get a lower case version of the first result of the `split`:

```
line.Split(" "c)(1).ToLower()
```

Making the first line:

```
Dim Convertcolumn = From line In System.IO.File.ReadLines("Path")
          Select line.Split(" "c)(1) & line.Split(" "c)(1).ToLower()
```

---

Update:

Now that you have explained your problem, I suggest using a library that deals with this kind of structured text file - use the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) to read the file and manipulate the values directly. You can use some of the static `Write*` methods on the [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z2ck8eh) class to write out the new file.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that before but I got 'ToLower' is not a member of 'System.Array'.

Comment: @user1413746 - It isn't, which is why you need to access an _element_ of the string array before calling `ToLower`.

Comment: Sorry how would I do that? I'm a newbie

Comment: @user1413746 - My example shows. `line.Split(" "c)(1).ToLower()`

Comment: I'm sorry I didnt see the response, I cant see what I'm doing wrong? I have used the coding and it just leaves my text file blank? I will edit my first post to show the coding.

Comment: @user1413746 - If you do edit, don't replace your current code, but _add_ it underneath so we can see the original.

Comment: Sorry I replaced the coding and cant see the original coding anymore :(

Comment: @user1413746 - Are you sure that `Test1.txt` contains anything? And the the lines do have more than one word each (you are accessing the _second_ element of the array when using `(1)` - try changing it to `(0)`?

Comment: Yes test1 contains data in three columns like D00001 BLACK user
D00002 BLACK user, I changed it to 0 but still the same problem?  in this case all i would like is to change the text in my textfile to D00001 black user
D00002 black user

Comment: sorry but whenever i try to show how the data is in my text file it keeps appending to the same line in my posts, basically the new line starts everytime with a new D* ie D00001 D00002 D00003

Comment: @user1413746 - Now that you explained exactly what you are trying to achieve, I have added a different option.